# Jquery: To switch from one page to another on drop-down list click

Tags: jquery, html

I have one drop down list in my page, which contains two options. What i want is, when user select second value in drop down list, another page should load. that means how to switch page on clicking on of the drop down box values.
for help i am putting my html code of drop down list.

```
        <select id = "viewList" class="fl width160">
            <option>Target</option>
            <option>Source</option>
        </select>
```

so now when user click on source option, another js page should open. and how should i write coding for that in a .js file(Jquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look you need to change your html code like this

```
 <select id = "viewList" class="fl width160">
        <option value ="Target">Target</option>
        <option value ="Source">Source</option>
    </select>

$("#viewList").change(function() {
        if( $("#viewList").val =='Target')
    {
        _loadTargetList();
    }
    else
    {
        _loadSourceList();
    }   
});
```

Here `_loadTargetList` and `_loadSourceList` both are the functions which will provide the location to load their html file or js files. Here is an example how to load html or js file
If you want to call js first then html through js then go for this one

```
codeLoadingMgr.loadInclude( path + '/Target.js', function() {
codeLoadingMgr.getHTML(path + '/Target.html', function(html) {
});
});
Other wise you can direct load the html also.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code:

```
  <select id ="viewList" class="fl width160">
      <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
      <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
  </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){$('#viewList').bind('change', function(){if($(this).val()) window.location=$(this).val();});});
</script>​
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DxJC/8/). Note that it might not work in JSfiddle because it runs the code in an iframe. You can test it [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7DxJC/8/show/)

Comment: i am looking for a answer like this, but still i didn't get it. if my source file is at c:/etc/source location then how will i pass this location, don't i need to call another function to load source page.?

Comment: c:/etc/source is a local file system location. Do you want to browse files stored locally? What is the url of the page which contains your select options?

Comment: no that, c location was just random example. exact one is like code/app/target and code/app/source

Comment: @VikasGupta Can you give me the location of the file which contains the html for the dropdown list? I need the location as it appears in your browser address bar.

Comment: look i am providing you the exact location of every file. I am doing the list coding in source.html file at location E:\Trans\WebContent\demo\code\app\sc\LoggedIn\sc\Source and this is also the location of sourceC.js file also where i want to do coding of onclick change event. and the another file targetC.js or target.html has at location E:\Trans\WebContent\demo\code\app\sc\LoggedIn\sc\target So i have provided you all locations, now plz tell me how to code for onclick change event in source.js file

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#viewList").change(function() {
   if ($(this).find(':selected').text() == 'Source')
      window.location = 'urltogoto';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @PenchoIlchev is valid, but if you don't want to use bind method, yo can try:

```
 <select id = "viewList" class="fl width160" onchange="change();">
        <option>Target</option>
        <option>Source</option>
    </select>​

function change(){
    url = $("#viewList option:selected").html();
    location.href = url;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FKjFC/